# CSS :hover:before not working as expected

Tags: css, css-selectors, pseudo-element

I have been using a theme and trying to tidy some pieces up.

The creator uses :before and :after to get the effect of dashed lines in the menu. The problem is when I hover over the li it shows the left vertical lines ok but the dashes to the link disappear

Here is a [JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/peqomologa/1/edit?html,css,output)

```
/* horizontal lines that disappear */
.nav-list > li .submenu > li:before,
.nav-list > li .submenu > li > ul > li:before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 9px;
    left: 25px;
    top: 17px;
    border-top: 1px dashed rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
}

.nav-list > li .submenu > li > ul > li:before {
    width: 22px;
}

/* vertical lines the stay */
.nav-list > li .submenu > li:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 22px;
    width: 0;
    border-left: 1px dashed rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `:after` pseudo-element shows up because it appears *after* the `a` element in the DOM (it is therefore stacked *above* the anchor element--order matters since they are sibling elements).

[image]

The `:before` pseudo-element wasn't showing up because it was being overlapped by the `a` element's background which was appearing above it. This is due to the fact that the `:before` pseudo-element appears *before* the `a` element in the DOM.

To solve this, you just need to increase the `z-index` of the `:before` pseudo-element (it is `auto` by default).

In doing so, the `:before` pseudo-element will not be overlapped when hovering over the anchor element because a [stacking context is established](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context) (order matters since they are siblings).

[**Updated Example**](http://jsbin.com/kufujobigi/1/edit?html,output)

```
.nav-list > li .submenu > li:before,
.nav-list > li .submenu > li > ul > li:before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 9px;
    left: 25px;
    top: 17px;
    border-top: 1px dashed rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: I had tried z-index on the hovered state (which I had added myself). Thanks

Answer (score 1):

That background color on hover covers the dash line. You can use `z-index` to fix that.

```
.nav-list > li .submenu > li:before,
.nav-list > li .submenu > li > ul > li:before {
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The before element was getting "covered",

adding z-index will do the trick:

```
/*add it to this block of CSS*/
.nav-list > li .submenu > li:before,
.nav-list > li .submenu > li > ul > li:before {
content: "";
display: block;
position: absolute;
width: 9px;
left: 25px;
top: 17px;
border-top: 1px dashed rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
z-index:111
}
```